# when I create an empty list in visual basic I get a Syntax Error message

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to create a list to contain the data in the cells of column 2 it returns me an error with the written: Syntax Error.

Where am I wrong?

```
Sub Ancora()

    'Ultimariga con dati
    EndRow = Worksheets("Completo").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Lista fornitori
    Dim fornitori As New List(Of string)
    
    For tot = 2 To EndRow
        
        If Not fornitori.Contains(Worksheets("Completo").Cells(tot, 2)) Then
        
            fornitori.Add (Worksheets("Completo").Cells(tot, 2))
        
        End If
    Next tot
    
    For i = 2 To EndRow
        
        For n = 0 To fornitori.Count()
        
                
            If Worksheets("Completo").Cells(i, 2) = fornitori(n) Then
        
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Sheets("Completo").Rows(i).Copy
                Sheets(fornitori(n)).Rows(i + 1).PasteSpecial
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            
            End If
    
        Next n
        
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim fornitori As New Collection`  look at the help for 'collection', may help?

Comment: `Dim fornitori As New List(Of string)` and `fornitori.Contains()` is VB.Net and not VBA.

Comment: VB.NET is a different language than VBA. See [VBA docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/); if you mean to write VBA code, try @Nathan_Sav's suggestion, and avoid surrounding method arguments with parentheses unless you're invoking a funciton and capturing its return value into a local (or implicit/expression) variable.

Comment: If I use '' 'Dim Suppliers As New Collection' '' it returns me:
Run-time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method